# Realizar acción si se cumplen varias condiciones

Tags: ios, swift

En mi `ViewController` tengo una serie de `Text Fields`. Cuando presiono el botón para enviar necesito que estos cumplan una serie de requisitos, y si lo hacen, realizar un post al servidor.

Tengo programadas las condiciones así, pero no sé como hacer para que el post se ejecute tras comprobar todo eso.

```
if titulo.text!.characters.count < 15 {

        let myColor = UIColor.redColor()
        titulo.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor

        caracteres.text = "Los espacios destacados deben contener un mínimo de 15 caracteres."

    } else {
        self.tituloenviar = titulo.text!
    }

    if descripcion.text!.characters.count < 15 {

        let myColor = UIColor.redColor()
        descripcion.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor

        caracteres.text = "Los espacios destacados deben contener un mínimo de 15 caracteres."

    } else {
        self.descripcionenviar = descripcion.text!
    }


    if fecha.text!.characters.count < 15 {

        let myColor = UIColor.redColor()
        fecha.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor

        caracteres.text = "Los espacios destacados deben contener un mínimo de 15 caracteres."

    } else {
        self.fechaenviar = fecha.text!
    }

    if horario.text!.characters.count < 15 {

        let myColor = UIColor.redColor()
        horario.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor

        caracteres.text = "Los espacios destacados deben contener un mínimo de 15 caracteres."

    } else {
        self.horarioenviar = horario.text!
    }

    if categoria.text!.characters.count < 1 {

        let myColor = UIColor.redColor()
        categoria.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor

        caracteres.text = "El espacio destacado debe corresponder con una de las categorías mencionadas."

    } else {
        self.categoriaenviar = categoria.text!
    }

}

// POST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagina que tienes una función llamada `sendData()`. Para comprobar que todo se cumple y solo se envía el `POST` después de cumplir todas las condiciones, lo podrías hacer así:

```
func sendData() {

    guard let t = titulo?.text where t.characters.count >= 15 else {

        // titulo.text no existe o bien tiene menos de 15 caracteres,
        // ya no se continua y se sale de la función...
        return
    }

    guard let d = descripcion?.text where d.characters.count >= 15 else {

        // descripcion.text no existe o bien tiene menos de 15 caracteres,
        // ya no se continua y se sale de la función...
        return
    }

    guard let f = fecha?.text where f.characters.count >= 15 else {

        // fecha.text no existe o bien tiene menos de 15 caracteres,
        // ya no se continua y se sale de la función...
        return
    }

    guard let h = horario?.text where h.characters.count >= 15 else {

        // horario.text no existe o bien tiene menos de 15 caracteres,
        // ya no se continua y se sale de la función...
        return
    }

    guard let c = categoria?.text where c.characters.count >= 1 else {

        // categoria.text no existe o bien tiene menos de 1 caracter,
        // ya no se continua y se sale de la función...
        return
    }

    // En este punto, todos los textos existen y además se cumplen las
    // condiciones. No hace falta guardarlo en variables globales y se 
    // pueden utilizar directamente, ya que t = titulo.text,
    // d = descripcion.text, f = fecha.text, h = horario.text
    // y c = categoria.text

    // POST

}
```

Dentro de cada `guard ... else` deberás poner el mensaje de error que has puesto en tu pregunta. Si algún `guard ... else` no se cumple, no se continua y se sale de la función.